# Randomizing column names in matrix

Tags: r, paste

I am trying to create a matrix that has a fixed set of column values, but within that fixed value, I would like to increment to a certain amount. Better explanation below... (hopefully)

For example, I would like to have column headers ODI.1.1, ODI.1.2, ... ODI.1.30, THEN go to ODI.2.1, ODI.2.2, ... and repeat to ODI.8.10. So the first number in each ODI value can go to 8 and the second number in the statement going anywhere from 1-30 at random.

This is the code I have right now. I know this isn't right as I set the columns to 30 right now, I was just trying to assign 30 columns incrementally the ODI.1.1, ODI1.2., .... values.

This is what I have currently, again I would like to be able to get up to ODI.8.1 values, but I'm not sure how to move on from here. Again I would like the 2nd number of the statement (ODI.1.**2**) to come at random. I'm don't quite sure how to do that... Below is a sample of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
    ODI.1.1 ODI.1.2 ...... ODI.1.10
    ODI.2.1 ODI.2.2 ...... ODI.2.18
    ODI.3.1 ODI.1.2 ...... ODI.3.28
```

Below is the code I have right now. I am able to print out a random list of ODI statements from 1-8 for the first number in the statement ODI.**1**.1, but I am not unable to create an ordered random list based on the 2nd number in the statement, ODI.1.**1**

```
n = 35
ODI = "ODI"
firstValue = 1:8
secondValue = 1:20

x <- sort(paste(ODI, firstValue, secondValue, sep ="."), 
        decreasing = FALSE)
x
```

With the code right now I'm getting this result ....

```
 "ODI.1.1"  "ODI.1.17" "ODI.1.9"  "ODI.2.10" "ODI.2.18" "ODI.2.2"  "ODI.3.11"
```

The 2nd value is not ordered like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 at random.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, but we can create all the possible combinations of these column names, from which you can then randomly sample a given amount.

```
wat=expand.grid(1:8,1:30)
wat=paste0("ODI.",wat[,"Var1",drop=T],".",wat[,"Var2",drop=T])
sample(wat,5)
[1] "ODI.5.18" "ODI.1.30" "ODI.3.20" "ODI.3.1"  "ODI.3.13"
```